# php foreach string to arguments in class

Tags: php, function, variables, foreach

It possible to put in one variable other variable's

```
$string = 'val1,val2,val3';
```

Then return `$string` like variables  `$val1` `$val2` `$val3`

and use it in `function myFunc($string) instead myFunc($val1, $val2, $val3)`

now i have

```
'MysqliDb' => array('cons' => true, 'cons_var' => 'db', 'cons_opt' => 'localhost,root,,test'),

$var = explode(',', $config['cons_opt']);
$$config['cons_var'] = new $module($config['cons_opt']);
```

to launch new class need 4 arguments. Can it make with 1 without editing class. ?
I need `$config['cons_opt']` return 4 variables like in array.

Comment: This is usually better done with an array, to avoid the need to parse the mess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/explode) function to separate a string by specific chracters. This will produce an array, which in turn can be used inside your function.

So, for example:

```
function myFunc($string)
{
    $myVars = explode(',', $string);
    foreach($myVars as $var)
    {
        // Now do something with $var
    }
}
```